# TypeScript split interface from class + namespace

Tags: typescript, inversion-of-control

In TypeScript, I have a class merged with a namespace
(foo.ts):

```
export class C {
  foo(): Foo { ... }
}
export namespace C {
  type Foo = ...
  ...
}
```

In preparation for using inversify, I want to put an interface for this class in a different file. I tried something like this:

(interfaces.ts)

```
export interface IC {
  foo (): C.Foo
  ...
}
export namespace C {
  type Foo = ...
}
```

(foo.ts)

```
import { C, IC } from './interfaces'

export class C {
  foo (): Foo { ... }
}
```

However, compiling foo.ts gives me the error: "Individual declarations in merged declaration 'C' must be all exported or all local." I guess this means I've imported the namespace, but I haven't exported it (though I would expect that exporting the class should export the merged entity). How can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Aha -- writing up my question led me to an answer. foo.ts can be changed to:

```
import { C, IC } from './interfaces'

class C {
  foo (): Foo { ... }
}

export { C }
```

It does seem odd that separate export is required, but nice to know that it works.

Comment: hmm... doesn't fully work, though. If a third module imports C from `foo.ts`, it only imports the class, not the namespace (?!). Will leave up for the moment, but will accept a better way.